# How do I set params max and offset in the List in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

I am stuck at a point where i am fetching a list from domain and save it into another list. How do i pass param to the newly created list

the code looks likes below:

```
 params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        params.offset = params.offset as Integer ?: 0



        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        date2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        def MonthStartDate =date.getTime()
        def MonthEndDate =date2.getTime()
        int monthMaxDays = MonthEndDate - MonthStartDate + 1


        Calendar cal0 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal0.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
     def myNewList  = new ArrayList<DomainABCTYPE>()
            def perDayDates = new ArrayList<Date>()




            for(int i=0;i<monthMaxDays;i++) {
                Date date1 = cal0.getTime();
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                Date calDate = cal.getTime();


              def myListPerDay = DomainABCTYPE.findAllByStartDateLessThanAndEndDateGreaterThanEquals(calDate, date1, params)



                int k=0
                for(;k < myListPerDay .size(); k++){
                    myNewList.add(myListPerDay .get(k))
                    perDayDates.add(date1)
                    }


                cal0.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)


            }


            render(view: "index", model:[ListInstance:myNewList ,ListCount:myNewList.size(), DatesList:perDayDates, MonthStartDate: MonthStartDate, MonthEndDate: MonthEndDate])

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/mailinglist/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/mailinglist/core/MailingListScheduleController.groovy) on how you can pass pagination params directly into a GORM find method.

I was briefly looking over your code in all honesty it all looks insane, you are calculating a date diff then iterating the date diff to find records.

Why not write a [HQL query](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugin/queuemail/QueueMailApiService.groovy#L391-L397) and use `between`

```
where a.date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2
```

In short all of that could be done with 1 lookup and no nested iterations lookup should be needed

Comment: I need to check data for each day of a month ...How to write the gorm for checking a range of dates like from 1st to 30th that which date is lying in the range of two columns startdate and enddate.. i.e i used for loop here

Comment: all depends on what you are collecting per day, counting of occurance, actual record in a given day either way there are still other things that could be done that would reduce db requirements like above either by doing it once then building own map out of it or thinking more clearly as to what is being acheived and if HQL query or even raw sql would suffice in one query